# HTML import Amazon s3 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, polymer, web-component, html-imports

I am loading all my project's resources from a cdn with `cors` enabled, however html imports fail on the first page load (then succeed on loads after it).

```
link(rel="import" id="htmlImports" href=`components.html` async)
```

producing the following error:

```
s3 amazon No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have search almost every related page and tried a million solution such as:

1. adding cors headers on the s3 bucket, some say that range solved their issue, some said that the expose header solved their issue, i added all and toggled between them, yet the same issue.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
       <CORSRule>
           <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
           <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
           <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
           <ExposeHeader>ETAG</ExposeHeader>
           <ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
           <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
           <ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
           <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
           <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
           <AllowedHeader>range</AllowedHeader>
           <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
       </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>`

2. in the cors spec, it is said that duplicate cors header will cause the request to fail, so i made sure no duplicates are there.
3. preflight request is enabled on the server and contains all the required configurations (allowed headers etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The solution to my issue was to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the import link

```
link(rel="import", id="htmlImports", href=`components.html`,
     async, crossorigin="anonymous")
```

by default s3 bucket sends a `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header, thus by adding `crossorigin="anonymous"`

> Cross-origin CORS requests for the element will have the omit credentials flag set.

this will get the html import request to work everytime.

## Note

*if anyone has an alternative or can explain the behavior in details please do!*